# HTTP Handler in MVC Project Yielding 404s

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httphandler

I've created an MVC Project that on button click it's suppose to save the contents of the the page as an .xlsx file.  This works fine in Chrome/FF but not in IE 9 and below.

To handle this edge case I've implemented an HTTP Handler.  The weird thing is when in debugging (VS 2013) "without breakpoints" the code works just fine and I'm able to download the excel file in IE.  But when I'm not debuging and just browse the page I get a 404: **Requested URL: /Home/ExportHandler.axd**  I wonder why am I getting a 404 and why is my route electing to put /Home in url, is there a way to remove it?  Any ways here's the code:

HTTP HANDLER

```
    namespace MvcApplication2
{
    public class ExportHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.Form["contentType"] != null &&
               context.Request.Form["fileName"] != null &&
               context.Request.Form["data"] != null)
            {
                context.Response.Clear();
                context.Response.ContentType = context.Request.Form["contentType"].ToString();
                context.Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
                context.Response.Expires = 0;
                context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-transfer-encoding", "binary");
                context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition",
                                              "attachment; filename=" + context.Request.Form["fileName"].ToString());
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(Convert.FromBase64String(context.Request.Form["data"].ToString()));
                context.Response.Flush();
                context.Response.End();
            }
        }
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
    }
}
```

MVC ROUTE

```
public class RouteConfig {
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

WEB.CONFIG

```
    <location path="Files">
    <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add type="MvcApplication2.ExportHandler" verb="*" path="ExportHandler.axd" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  </location>
```